# Adding hyperlink button column in silverlight grid from codebehind?

Tags: silverlight, button, hyperlink

Since I am building the columns from code-behind, I need to attach  hyperlink into one of the columns from code behind. And also, I need to add the click event.

How can I do that and its data-binding in code behind? Please advise.

Thanks
AJ

Answer (score 0):

[Defining Columns](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Defining-Columns-for-a-Silverlight-DataGrid.aspx)

Take a look at the section about adding template columns.  In a nutshell you can add them with a resource or by using `XamlReader.Load(string)` to load a DataTemplate.